# Any way to change lightdm unity greeter background without changing current config files?

Tags: unity, lightdm, login-screen

About changing lightdm unity greeter background image, most answers are to change /usr/share/glib2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml.  Is there any way to change the default wallpaper in lightdm unity greeter without changing the file?  Like an override file.

I'm making a debian package that would apply our own artwork after installing.  I can't changing the file content in my maintainer script, which would violate debian packaging policy.  I can change the unity desktop background by adding a schema override file in the same folder, but I couldn't find a way to change the lightdm background with similar way.

Comment: I added a override file with

[com.canonical.unity-greeter]
background=<my_background_path>

Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04, it is possible to do this programmatically via the dconf database for user lightdm e.g.

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch --exit-with-session \
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background /usr/share/backgrounds/Tie_My_Boat_by_Ray_García.jpg
```

The change takes effect when lightdm is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

add to package:

`debian/install` with content

```
debian/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

`debian/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override` with content

```
[com.canonical.unity-greeter] 
draw-user-backgrounds=false
background='/foo/wallpaper.png'
```

debian/postinst with content

```
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```